# inequality by taking reciprocal or other way to check if pole lies inside unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

If $ a^2$ <1 is given in the problem then how do we prove that the pole  z=1/a lies outside the unit circle ?

Answer (score 0):

$z\in\mathbb{C}$ lies in the unit circle if and only if $|z|^2=1$.

If $z=\frac{1}{a}$, one has: $|z|^2=\frac{1}{a^2}>1$ by hypothesis. Whence, $z$ is not in the unit circle.

Notice that you must assume that $a\neq 0$ to define $z$.

**Remarks.**

- The unit circle is the set of $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $a^2+b^2=1$.
- $|a+ib|^2=a^2+b^2$.

Comment: i think it would be correct to say that z  lies in unit circle if |z|<=1

Comment: it doesn't seem to be correct

Comment: Not really, $\{|z|\leqslant 1\}$ is the unit disk. With my remarks, you can understand why the unit circle is indeed $\left\{|z|^2=1\right\}$. However, it's correct to say that if $z$ lies in the unit circle, then $|z|\leqslant 1$. Notice that this is only an implication.